# How to frame corner of staircase header for a stairwell opening? Do you use a hanger here?

Tags: framing, joists, engineering

I'm designing a staircase and was a little curious on how to frame out the stairwell opening where the header meats the existing joists. There will be a double 1.75"(x2) LVL header joined up against an existing joists that have been sister-ed up on the opposite side.

The question is, do I put a joist hanger here or what other standard methods can be used that are structurally sound? The engineering drawings call out a double handger here but wont the hanger flange interfere with my steel staircase stringers. Are there any other connection methods available?

I'm just wondering what other options exist out there that could be IRC code compliant. How do house framers usually do this? I feel like I've seen many a stairwell opening without a single joist hanger.

- Floor Live Load: 40psf
- Hanger: Ddouble 2x8 Hanger U28-2

[image]
[image: drawings]

Comment: The image suggests that the stair stringer is steel and that it is bolted to the joist, so why not bolt the header to the side of the stringer ? **I am NOT an engineer**.

Comment: No worries, I'm not the engineering police... any decision made will be run through him anyways.  I'm just exploring options and seeing what people typically do.